What is the base of defining eccentricity like this?

In an Introduction to Modern Astrophysics, the author first derived the Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector, and then used the vector to derive the equation of orbit ($\mu$ is reduced mass, $\mu = \frac{m_1m_2}{m_1+m_2}$, $D$ is the LRL vector, $M$ is total mass of the system).
My question is in the equation
$$\frac{L^2}{\mu} = GM\mu r(1+\frac{D \cos \theta}{GM\mu}).$$
The authors define eccentricity as $\frac{D}{GM\mu}$, but I just don't see why this fraction generates the eccentricity of the orbit. My guess is that this is the only thing that is missing from the polar equation of conic section ($r= \frac{l}{1+e\cos \theta}$, $l$ is semi-latus rectum) so people just defined it like this.

You are correct. Other treatments have already defined eccentricity to be the coefficient $e$ in $1+e\cos\vartheta$ and so it is sensible to compare those equations and deduce that a legitimate definition of the eccentricity this way.

@naturallyInconsistent, so what you are essentially saying is one had already proven that the trajectory of a body around another body is a conic section, so this derivation must also match the equation for a conic section so it is natural to define eccentricity like this?

It is not about proven. It is about definitions and prior work. Other people had worked on conic sections and orbits, and so this work has to obtain a compatible definition. Yes, it is natural to define eccentricity this way.

The equation you are considering represents a conic in polar coordinates, and in that form, the coefficient of $\cos \theta$ is the eccentricity. Of course, such an identification is consistent with other formulas for the same quantity (see, for instance, the relevant Wikipedia page).
